# Mongodb, storing comments to a specific post

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

My userSchema looks something like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: ......},
  email: { type..... },

  test1: {
    [
      [0] { test: Array },
      [1] { test: Array }      
    ]
  }
)};
```

With a few other objects not included here. In the object that's in test1 there is stored some data to which i want to add or somehow bind an array of comments. The problem is that I'm not sure which is the best way to implement this? If i should create a new commentSchema and somehow connect the comments with the object or how to do it. Can anyone give me some tips on how to implement it?

Comment: Something like this? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create your schema as follows:

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    message: String,
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: ......},
    email: { type..... },
    ...
    test1: {
    comments: [CommentSchema]
    }
    ... OR
    comments: [CommentSchema]
)};
```

or if you are trying to do something like posts with comments try

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    comments: [CommentSchema]
    postBody: String
})

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: ......},
    email: { type..... },
    ...
    posts: [PostSchema] 
    ...
)};
```